# C Pipe Write and Read never hit EOF

Tags: c, pipe, pthreads, fork

I posted the issue with `fork()` and `pipe()`, but later I saw that the problem was only in `pipe()`.

So I'm removing `fork()` code from here.

**Problem:** Writing in `pipe()`, and reading from `pipe()` but never reach the `EOF` condition in loops

Here is a simplification code of the problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int fd[2];

int main() {
    if(pipe(fd) == 0) {
        printf("Pipe is Open\n");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        close(fd[1]);
        write(fd[0], &i, sizeof(int));
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int value;
        close(fd[0]);
        read(fd[1], &value, sizeof(int));
        close(fd[1]);
        printf("%d\n", value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Pipe is Open
4
4
4
4
4
```

Comment: There is no `fork` in the code you've shown. Do note that asking users to go off-site to review code is poor etiquette. Please post a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) within your question. Please try to include a more accurate description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use `<fcntl.h>` to work properly

`<fcntl.h>` is a file control removed the need to close the pipe off my hands in order for it to reach EOF

```
if (fcntl(fd[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
        exit(-1);
```

Where `fd[0]` is the pipe created

Without the `fcntl()` the code never hit the EOF condition

The implementations below, unlike the previous code, the `close()` has been removed and the `fcntl()` has been added to handle this, giving the output as desired to read values ​​inside a pipe in a loop until reaching EOF.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int fd[2];
int main() {
    if(pipe(fd) == 0) {
        printf("Pipe is Open\n");
    }

    if (fcntl(fd[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
        exit(-1);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        write(fd[1], &i, sizeof(int));  
    }
    
    int status;
    while(1) {
        int value;
        status = read(fd[0], &value, sizeof(int));
        printf("status: %d\n", status);
         if(status > 0) {
             printf("%d\n", value);
        } else {
             // END of FILE
             printf("\nEOF\n");
             break;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Pipe is Open
status: 4
0
status: 4
1
status: 4
2
status: 4
3
status: 4
4
status: -1

EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite wanting to `read` in a loop multiple times, you `close` the file descriptor immediately after the first read, so that subsequent `read`s must fail; in addition, you forget to check the `read`s' return value for error and so use the unchanged `value` from the previous loop cycle.